# Rails + Devise => Use Devise Mailer globally to handle all of the mail sending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer

I would like to use the devise mailer globally, 
since that way I would not have to add another mailer to my app and just use the devise one, to send custom mails outside the devise views/controllers.

Already digged to long for this, anyone know how I can make this possible?

Comment: No device for ruby on rails, I tagged in ruby on rails mayb I should edit to make that clear in the title also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the point is to only have *one* mailer, it's perhaps more straightforward to have your one single mailer just extend the DeviseMailer.  E.g. in app/mailer

```
# app/mailers/mailer.rb
class Mailer < Devise::Mailer

  # add all your custom mailer methods
end
```

This setup will, for example, cause all emails (from Devise and otherwise) to all be sent with the `app/layouts/mailer.html.erb` template.

Note that to do this you do need to move the Devise mailer templates from `app/views/devise/mailer` to just `app/views/mailer`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, still learning ROR this is very simple if you think about it! I try